# Pointers to methods & templates problem, C++

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

There are 2 template classes A and B having 2 private members a1, a2 and b1, b2.

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
private:
    T a1, a2;

public:
    T getA1 () const {return a1;}
    T getA2 () const {return a2;}

};


template <typename T>
class B
{
private:
    T b1, b2;

public:
    T getB1 () const {return b1;}
    T getB2 () const {return b2;}

};
```

In the class Test there is a need for 2 pointers pointing to getters.

```
class Test
{
  private:
    template <typename T>
    static T ( *getFirst ) ();

    template <typename T>
    static T ( *getSecond ) ();

}


template <typename T>
T ( * Test::getFirst ) ()  =  &A<T>::getA1; //Pointer to getA1, error

template <typename T>
T ( * Test::getSecond ) ()  =  &B<T>::getB2; //Pointer to getB2, error

int main
{
   A <double> a;
   B <double> b;

   double c = a.getFirst + b.getSecond;
}
```

T represents fundamental data types... Is it possible implement this code without specialization (i.e. pointers to class template members) or those "pointers" should be specialized? Thanks for any examples...

Comment: I have tried to compose an answer, but failed for one reason: I don't get it what you intend to do with your class Test. You provide a definition of it which has errors, but you don't use it anywhere. The way to fix those errors depends largely on how are you planning to use it. Some of the answers below may prove useful to you, but in order to get the proper answer you need to provide an example usage of Test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing illegal things. See this,

```
template <typename T>
static T ( *getFirst ) ();
```

Here you're trying to define *template function pointer* which is illegal in C++.

The C++ Standard says in $14/1,

> A template defines a family of **classes**
>   or **functions**.

Please note that it does **not** say "a template defines a family of *classes*, *functions* ***or function pointers***". So what you're trying to do is, defining *"a family of function pointers"* using template, which isn't allowed.

---

If you want function pointer you can do something like this,

```
template <class T>
struct A
{
   static T (*FunctionPointer)(); //function pointer
};

struct B
{
   template <class T>
   static T Function(); //static function, not function pointer
};

int (*A<double>::FunctionPointer)() = &B::Function<double>;
```

Yet better alternative is : use [function object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object). :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks... How will look the code when Function will not be static? Could I ask you also for a short example using function objects in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's not possible.

First, you cannot declare a pointer to template function, only pointer to a concrete function. 
Second, you tried to declare pointer to free function but `A::getA1` is a member function with implicit `this` argument, so semantic doesn't match.

You can do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    static T get() { return T() };
};

template <typename T>
struct Holder
{
    typedef T(A<T>::*F_ptr)();
    static F_ptr f_ptr;
};


template <typename T>
typename Holder<T>::F_ptr Holder<T>::f_ptr  =  &A<T>::get;
```

to keep pointer to template function as a member of template class

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
template <typename T>
T (*Test::getFirst)() = &A<T>::getA1; //Pointer to getA1, error
```

Has two problems: One is that `&A<T>::getA1` is of type `T (A::*)()const` but getFirst is of type `T (*)()`. These are not compatible because the former is a pointer to a member function, while the latter is not.

The second problem with the line is that the objects created would differ only in their return type. Just like you cannot manually declare both `double (A::*getFirst)()const` and `char (A::*getFirst)()const`, you also cannot create a template that would automatically declare both of them.

The line:

`double c = a.getFirst + b.getSecond;`

Has its own set of problems that may or may not relate to the issue at hand.

Sorry for this "non answer." maybe if you talked more about what you are trying to accomplish, rather than how you are trying to accomplish it, we will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems quite confused, so I'm not sure I really understood what you are asking for... here is an adaptation of your example that compiles.

```
// This is one template class A with two getters
template <typename T>
class A
{
private:
    T a1, a2;

public:
    T getA1 () const {return a1;}
    T getA2 () const {return a2;}
};

// This is another unrelated template class, with two other getters
template <typename T>
class B
{
private:
    T b1, b2;

public:
    T getB1 () const {return b1;}
    T getB2 () const {return b2;}
};

// These are declarations of generic "getFirst" and "getSecond"
template<typename T1, typename T2>
T1 getFirst(const T2& t);

template<class T1, class T2>
T1 getSecond(const T2& t);

// Here I'm specializing getFirst/getSecond for the A template
template<class X>
double getFirst(const A<X>& a)  { return a.getA1(); }

template<class X>
double getSecond(const A<X>& a) { return a.getA2(); }

// Here I'm doing the same for the B template
template<class X>
double getFirst(const B<X>& b)  { return b.getB1(); }

template<class X>
double getSecond(const B<X>& b) { return b.getB2(); }

// Now I can use getFirst/getSecond with either A or B
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   A<double> a;
   B<double> b;
   double c = getFirst(a) + getSecond(b);
   return 0;
}
```